# Manipulating the location of data points in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple data frame of 3 columns. Column 1 contains samples (A-D) collected over time. Column 2 identifies linked pairs within the data that represent interacting sites. There may be up to 10 identifier pairs in any one sample. Column 3 ranks (1-3) the strength of the interaction between the identifiers

The first task was to bin and graph the data. As the rank values are integers, I have used geom_jitter() to distribute them at alternate locations within the bin. I then assign shape/color to each unique identifier pair so that I can follow individual pairs between the samples (i.e. whether they increase or decrease in rank).

This is what I have done to date:

```
Sample <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","D")
Rank <- c(3,3,1,3,3,2,3,3,2,1)
Site <- c(101202,102203,101201,102203,101202,101202,102203,102203,101201,101202)
DataSet <- as.data.frame(cbind(Sample,Rank,Site))
ggplot(data=DataSet, aes(x=Sample, y=Rank, group=factor(Site), colour = factor(Site))) + geom_jitter(aes(shape = factor(Site)),  size = 4) + geom_vline(xintercept=seq(0.5,length(unique(DataSet$Sample)), 1), lwd=0.5, colour="black",linetype = "dotted") + geom_hline(yintercept=seq(0.5, length(unique(DataSet$Rank))+0.5, 1), lwd=0.5, colour="black",linetype = "dotted") + scale_shape_manual(values=c(16:18)) + theme(legend.position="none", panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

[image: What I get]

My question is: To further aide visualization, I would like assign each unique identifier pair to the same location within the bin. Is there a way to achieve this?

To illustrate what I mean, please find the provided mocked-up figure.

[image: What I want]

So for example, the identifier pair in blue is ranked 1 in samples A to D and its position within the bin is the same (i.e. top left corner). The identifier pair in green changes rank but its location is to the bottom-right of the respective bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a start. It is based on the idea that jitter is a random addition to the x and y coordinates of a point. So, if we add predetermined values to x and y, based on the site ID, points should appear in the same spot for the same sites.

First, we generate a dataframe of relative positions based on site-id.

```
position_data <- data.frame(id=1:10, 
                            x=c(rep(seq(-0.4,0.4,length.out=3),3),0),
                            y = rep(seq(0.4,-0.4,length.out=4),c(3,3,3,1)))
```

We check wether this distribution is what we had in mind:

```
 ggplot(position_data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_text(aes(label=id))
```

[image]

Then, we merge this with the original dataset:

```
#generate identifier
DataSet$Site_ID <- as.numeric(DataSet$Site)

plotdata <- merge(DataSet, position_data, by.x="Site_ID",by.y="id")
```

Then we add the x-es and y-s to the Rank and Sample-positions:

```
plotdata$y <- plotdata$y + as.numeric(plotdata$Rank)
plotdata$x <- plotdata$x + as.numeric(plotdata$Sample)
```

Now we can plot:

```
ggplot(data=plotdata, aes(x=x, y=y, group=factor(Site), colour = factor(Site),shape=factor(Site))) +
  geom_point(size=5)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(0.5,length(unique(DataSet$Sample)), 1), lwd=0.5, colour="black",linetype = "dotted") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=seq(0.5, length(unique(DataSet$Rank))+0.5, 1), lwd=0.5, colour="black",linetype = "dotted") + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16:18)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:length(unique(plotdata$Sample)),labels=sort(unique(plotdata$Sample)),name="Sample") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:length(unique(plotdata$Rank)), labels=sort(unique(plotdata$Rank)),name="Rank")
```

Note that our axes went from factor to numeric, so we had to add a custom scale to both.

Result:
[image]

Comment: Great. I wouldn't have known where to begin trying to define and implement my own x and y coordinates. 

When I tried to apply the solution to my own (larger) data set, I had difficulties merging DataSet and position_data. I ended up adding a new column to DataSet defining unique values to the "Site_ID" and matching these to the values in position_data$id using 
    transform(top_sites, id=match(id, unique(id)))

Comment: What kind of issues? I don't know what the datatype of Site is, you might need to convert to factor before converting to numeric when it's a character-variable.

Comment: Sorry, I pressed add comment before finishing my train of thought.

In your original solution the DataSet and position_data were data frames of equal length. position_data defines the coordinates. In my larger data set there are 50 rows and when I used by.x or by.y, I received errors. My workaround is fine but its clumsy

Comment: A solution might be to use 'all.x=T'.

Comment: I tried 'all.x=T' but got a lot of NAs. Anyway, my workaround solves the conundrum. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: You're welcome. If the current solution suffices, would you consider accepting it? Not to beat my drum, but also for archival purposes.